# Різниця між числівниками 1000^n і рештою числівників

Tags: числівники

Набори кількісних числівників з цих рядів

- 1, 2, ... 9
- 11, 12, ... 19
- 10, 20, ... 90
- 100, 200, ... 900

концептуально відрізняються від числівників з ряду

- 1000, 1 000 000, 1 000 000 000, ...

І в мене три питання.
Чи є у другої групи окрема назва?
Як пояснюється ця різниця лінгвістично?
І до якої групи тут належить 0?

---

Дозвольте пояснити, що саме я саме маю на увазі

### 1. Власний рід і animacy

- Кількісні числівники з першої групи не мають незмінної характеристики роду та живого. І з ними неможливо узгодити прикметник напряму, без еліптичної конструкції (ба́чу черво́ні два́ ?).
- Другі ж мають власний рід і є неживі, їх можна використовувати напряму (черво́на ти́сяча). Вони скоріш поводяться як іменник, що називає цифру (черво́на дві́йка), але ж то вже іменник, а не числівник.

### 2. Узгодження з іменними частинами мови

- Узгоджуючи перші числівники зі словом з будь-яким родом, вони, або приймуть форму (ба́чу одного́ чолові́ка, ба́чу одну́ жі́нку), або залишаться незмінними (ба́чу двадцатьо́х чоловікі́в, ба́чу двадцатьо́х жіно́к). Те ж саме буде з істотою/неістотою (ба́чу два́ олівці́, ба́чу дво́х чоловікі́в).
- Числівниками другої групи ніколи не змінюють власного роду (ба́чу ти́сячу чоловікі́в, ба́чу ти́сячу жіно́к, ба́чу ти́сячу олівці́в)

Цей пункт не є дуже вагомим, але він допомогає з наступним

### 3. Узгодження з числівниками

- Числівники з першої групи не підпорядковують інші числівники, вони тільки модифікують число і (іноді) відмінок обʼєкта (ба́чу ші́сть я́блук)
- Числівнкик з другої групи на додаток то модифікації обʼєкта також підпорядковують до себе частину числівники з першої групи, які мають узгоджуватись вже не з обʼєктом напряму (ба́чу дві́ ти́сячі два́ я́блука, ба́чу сі́м мільйо́нів сімо́х жіно́к).

Чи є у другої групи окрема назва?
Як пояснюється ця різниця лінгвістично?
І до якої групи тут належить 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Це відбувається тому, що одне і те саме слово *тисяча* може бути як числівником, так і іменником.

Джерело [1], сторінка 165 (онлайн документ сторінка 170):

> Треба розрізняти числівники і слова інших частин мови.
> Порівняймо:
>
> | Числівник | Іменники | Прислівники | Дієслово |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | *три* | *трійка, одиниця, сотня, десяток* | *втретє* | *потроїти* |

У даному випадку:

- *тисяча людей* — числівник;
- *червона тисяча* — іменник.

Окрім слів *тисяча, мільйон, мільярд*, що згадані у запитанні, є інші слова, які поводять себе так само:

- Просто іменники: *трійка, десятка, десяток, сотня*;
- Дробові: *половина, третина, чверть*;
- Інші: *відсоток, частина, меншість, група, зграя*.

Вони також відмінюються згідно *власного* граматичного роду (найчастіше, Жін.); до них цілком можливо застосовувати прикметники, тощо.

---

#### Висновок

> Чи є у другої групи окрема назва?

**Іменники**.

> Як пояснюється ця різниця лінгвістично?

Це **омоніми**. *Тисяча* (іменник) і *тисяча* (числівник) — це два різні слова, які пишуться та/або вимовляються однаково.

> І до якої групи тут належить 0?

**Іменник.** Він проявляє усі вищенаведені властивості.
Певно, ви його відокремили, бо число *нуль* менше ніж *один*, а усі наведені у запитанні іменники мають значення, що кратне до *тисяча* — що і викликало непорозуміння.
Насправді, числове значення у даному випадку не відіграє ролі.

---

#### Джерела

1. [Підручник Українська мова, 6 клас (Заболотний, 2014)](https://pidruchnyk.com.ua/512-ukrayinska-mova-zabolotniy-6-klas.html)
2. [ЗНО. ЧВЕРТЬ. Числівник чи все-таки іменник?](https://olesya12142111.blogspot.com/2019/05/blog-post_24.html)

Comment: Дякую, але мене все ще цікаво який механізм змушує числівник "5" в "бачу 5000 чоловіків" узгоджуватись з неістотою жіночого роду "тисячі", замість істоти чоловічого роду "чоловіків".

Comment: @Teivaz, "5" - це число, а "п'ять" - це числівник. Щоб позначити число 5000, необхідно використати складений числівник "п'ять тисяч", в якому "п'ять" вказує на кількість розрядів числа / кількість порядків (тисяч). Відповідно до правил Українського правопису відбувається узгодження числівника з іменником, а не окремих його частин.

Comment: Тобто ви хочете сказати, що в "бачу 1000 чоловіків" слово "1000" то числівник, а в "бачу 5000 чоловіків" слово "1000" є іменником?

Comment: @Teivaz замініть «п'ять тисяч чоловіків» на «п'ять дюжин чоловіків» або «п'ять вагонів чоловіків». Слова «тисяча», «дюжина» та «вагон» відмінюються як звичайні іменники.

Comment: Насправді, якщо цікавитеся лінгвістикою, то концепція числівника тягне прадавню історію і має коріння у вигляді word classifiers. Наприклад, щоб сказати [тайською](http://www.thai-language.com/ref/classifier-list) мовою «п'ять студентів», ми кажемо «студент п'ять особа». «П'ять котів» = «Кіт п'ять тіло». «П'ять цигарок» = «цигарка п'ять классифікатор_на_позначення_продовгуватих_предметів». «П'ять пива» = «пиво п'ять скло». Чимось подібне до нашого «п'ять пляшок пива».

Comment: @Teivaz
1000 і 5000 - це числа. "Одна тисяча" і "п'ять тисяч" - це слова на позначення чисел, вони називаються ч и с л і в н и к а м и.

Answer (score 1):

## Числівники нуль, тисяча, мільйон, мільярд

### [Український правопис:](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf)

> **§ 105. Відмінювання кількісних числівників**
>
> 11. Числові назви **ти́сяча**, **мільйо́н**, **мілья́рд** відмінюємо як іменники відповідних відмін.

Після числівників **тисяча**, **мільйон**, **мільярд**, **нуль** іменник незмінно стоїть у родовому відмінку множини: *тисяча **тонн***, *тисячею **тонн***, *тисячами **тонн***, *нуль **одиниць***.

Числівники **мільйон**, **мільярд** і **нуль** відмінюються як іменники чоловічого роду другої відміни, твердої та м'якої груп, а числівник **тисяча** — як іменник жіночого роду першої відміни мішаної групи.

### Лінгвістика

Відповідники числівникові **тисяча** є в західнослов'янських та частині південнослов'янських мов. Щодо його походження немає одностайної думки.

Числівник **мільйон** утворено від кореня латинського слова **mille** — **тисяча**. Уперше це слово з'явилося в XIV ст., в українську мову увійшло в XVIII ст.

Числівник **мільярд** уживається з XIX ст. Деякий час для позначення цієї ж кількості вживався й інший числівник **більйон**, який зараз майже зовсім вийшов з ужитку.

Числівник **нуль** увійшов в європейські мови з середньовічної латини, де **nullus numerus** означало ніяке число (вітсутність лічби).

> Систему числівників українська мова успадкувала від [давньоруської](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), хоч
> назви одиниць вищого розряду давньоруська мова мала свої:
>
> ```
> 10 000 – тьма
> 100 000 – легіон
> 1 000 000 – леодр
> 10 000 000 – ворон
> 100 000 000 – колода.
> ```

### Власне кількісні числівники

До [власне-кількісних числівників](https://filologukraine.ucoz.ua/publ/mova/sulm/kilkisni_chislivniki/3-1-0-64)  належить насамперед 40 числових назв, оформлених як окремі слова. «‎Різним поєднанням цих 40 числівників в аналітичні [числові назви](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1r74NorgMGuDwcUWbVPlQ1LODgk-8vcOY/) передаються всі інші кількісні поняття» (СУЛМ, Д. Баранник, 1969, с. 238-239).

1. числа першого десятку (від 1 до 10);
2. числа другого десятку (від 11 до 19)
3. десятки (від 20 до 90);
4. сотні (від 100 до 1000, в т.ч. ***тисяча***);
5. числові назви ***мільйон***, ***мільярд***, ***нуль***.

**Трильйон (більйон)** та назви чисел більшого порядку є **науковими термінами**.

### Великі числа

**Великі числа** - це загальний термін, який використовується для опису чисел, які суттєво перевищують числа, з якими ми зазвичай працюємо у повсякденному житті. Визначення того, що вважається "великим" числом, може значно змінюватись в залежності від контексту. Наприклад, у математиці та науці "велике число" може означати число в діапазоні тисяч, мільйонів, мільярдів і навіть більше. Великі числа зазвичай позначаються з використанням [степенів десяти](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96_10) ([системи найменувань чисел](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB)).

### Правила найменування великих чисел

Сьогодні в світовій практиці не існує єдиного правила найменування багатозначних чисел, що ускладнює міжнародну систему інформації, а інколи призводить до прикрих і серйозних непорозумінь.

### Правило «n — 1»

Це правило Міжнародний комітет мір і ваги (МКМВ) рекомендує для вживання всім країнам Європи. Але, попри те, що країни Східної Європи (колишньої Ради економічної взаємодопомоги, до якої в складі СРСР входила і Україна) прийняли рекомендації МКМВ (стандарт РС-2625-71), сьогодні в Україні поширеніше правило «n — 1».

За правилом «n — 1» найменування відбувається за рахунок представлення багатозначного числа як 10^3n, де 3n — степінь з постійним множником 3, а n — змінне ціле додатне число. Назва числа складається з двох частин: перша — від французької чи латинської назви числа, яке на одиницю менше, ніж число n, і друга — слово «ільйон» («ильйон»). Наприклад, назва числа 10^12=10^3n, де n = 4, (n — 1) = 3, буде складатися з назви числа 3 (лат. tres — три) + «ільйон» — трильйон.

### Іменні назви степенів тисячі

```
10^3 (десять у третьому ступені) дорівнює 1,000 (тисяча)

10^6 (десять шостою мірою) дорівнює 1,000,000 (мільйон)

10^9 (десять у дев'ятому ступені) дорівнює 1,000,000,000 (мільярд)

10^12 (десять в дванадцятому ступені) дорівнює 1,000,000,000,000 (трильйон)

10^100 (десять в сотому ступені) має назву гугол.
```

### Числа Мерсенна

У деяких областях, таких як комп'ютерні науки або теорія інформації, великі числа можуть позначатися з використанням двійкової системи, де числа видаються ступенями двійки, а не десяти.

Числа виду **M(n)= 2^n − 1**, де n - натуральне число, називають **[Числами Мерсенна](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0)**.

[Найбільше відоме просте число](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE) дорівнює два в ступені 77232917 мінус один. Воно містить 23249425 десяткових цифр і було знайдене Патріком Ларошем 7 грудня 2018 року в рамках проекту GIMPS.

---

## Відповідь:

**Система** числівників **базується на**:

- десяти назвах чисел першого десятка: ***один, два, три, чотири, п’ять, шість, сім, вісім, дев’ять, десять***;
- шести числових назвах: ***нуль, сорок, сто, тисяча, мільйон, мільярд***.

Числівники **тисяча**, **мільйон**, **мільярд**, як і числівники вищих розрядів, зберігають категорії роду і числа. Тому, на мою думку, якщо назвати їх **«великі числа»** (високорозрядні / числа великого порядку ([розряд](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0), [порядок числа](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8)), відповідно до контексту буде цілком прийнятним і зрозумілим.

А **нуль** - це **ніскільки**, **ніщо**. Та його слід відносити до тієї ж групи, що і **великі числа**.

Comment: Мені здається, це не те, про що питає автор. Великі числа — це (нечітка) _математична_ категорія. А автора цікавила _мовознавча_ категорія — слова (числівники), які граматично узгоджуються певним чином. По-перше, числа (те, чим оперує математика) і числівники (тобто слова на позначення чисел; це те, чим оперує мовознавство) — це не одне й те саме. По-друге, як показав Be Brave Be Like Ukraine [у своїй відповіді](/a/7282), до категорії, про яку запитує автор, належать не лише слова на позначення великих чисел, а й, наприклад, слова _нуль_, _десяток_, _дюжина_, _сотня_.

Comment: @Sasha, щодо наведеного прикладу. Іменники десяток, дюжина, сотня, половина, третина, чверть властиві розмовному мовленню.